# CSS Changing background-image height

Tags: css

My css code looks like this:

```
body
{
   background-image(url:(...));
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   height:100%;
}
```

The Question is...How can I fit the background-image to the size of different 
screens (1024x768) or other....
I mean change the height dynamically for each size of screen?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
html {
        background: url(....) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

Have a look at this article...http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Thank you as well...I don't use "no-repeat" property,since i'm not using a full image for background...so I'm using repeat-x, to generate my background image...And the background-size property is CSS3...that could be a problem in older browsers

Comment: The method mentioned above by @Anish is CSS3 and will not work in older browsers. However, the link he gave has other options that will work great in most browsers. I'd try the other non-CSS3 options from the CSS-Tricks article and see which you like best.

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing the CSS class applied to the body tag using javascript; I suggest you to use a javascript library like jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$('body').removeClass('res1');
$('body').addClass('res2');
```

Using a library like jQuery you have not to worry about browser incompatibility.

Comment: Sorry,but I didn't understand...how does it helps me? For example: I can check the screen size (width & height) like this: $(window).height(); or $(window).width(); the question is how do I use that value in CSS...it's tricky because the background-image using repeat:repeat-x;

Comment: you can make an if statement and say something like: if($(window).height = xxx) ... then $('body').addClass('nameoftheclass'). What you are trying to do with this is to change the size depending o the resolution; you are not going to modify the CSS, just change the css class you are aplying.

Answer (score 0):

```
<HEAD>
<style>
body{margin:0px}
.bg{
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index:0;
}
</style>

</HEAD>
<BODY>

<img class="bg" src="pic.jpg" border="0">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer... The thing is that i don't want to use a image tag <img> for my background-image....